# Use function as worksheet name

Tags: vba, excel

I have a function that finds the name of the Nth sheet.

How can I then use this to declare a worksheet name in a sub on another module?

I have the following, but it produces an error:

```
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet

Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
Set ws = Module2.FirstBBSName
```

Where FirstBBSName is the name of the function.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Does `FirstBBSName` return a `String` or a `Worksheet` ?

Comment: it is simply `Application.Volatile True
FirstBBSName = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(6).Name`

Comment: So try `Set ws = wb.Worksheets(Module2.FirstBBSName)`

Comment: Yes that no longer gives an error for that line thanks. I receive one further down in my code but I shall ask a separate question as I don't think it is related.